# Graze or Grazes?

Tags: grammar

My sister in law is creating a poem where she is using the word cattle. We are stuck because the line goes: 
“Where cattle graze
miles away from the city”

We are unsure if the correct form of graze to use is graze or grazes. Because when we read it out loud the word grazes naturally comes out but is it ungrammatical to use grazes with the word cattle?

Comment: I graze, you graze, he grazes, we graze, you graze they graze.  A cow grazes, cattle graze.

Comment: @HotLicks Are you on one of those fad diets?

Comment: @Cascabel -- The cattle is lowing???

Comment: Poetry don't have to stick to no grammar.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cattle+is%2Ccattle+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccattle%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccattle%20are%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccattle%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccattle%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: And if you look at the "hits", virtually all uses of "cattle is" are in sentences like "The iron requirement of cattle is believed to be less than that of swine."

Comment: Hi Jessica, does "Cows graze" feel okay?  It really is the same thing.

Comment: @Cascabel Although you're right that *cattle* is an uncountable mass noun that therefore requires "partitive" constructions like *ten head of cattle* for counting, it turns out that unlike nearly all such mass nouns, *cattle* is actually one of those famed "pluralia tantum" which by definition necessarily have no singular and take plural concord: *those cattle are stampeding*.  You may be thinking of words like Spanish *ganado* or *rebaño*, which are both much less exotic grammatically than English *cattle*.

Comment: @J.Taylor Poets it sticks to no grammar / Hit word with the liter'ry hammer / As long as they rhyme / We no give a dime / 'Cause in it we are for the glamour

Comment: Here's an identical question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/can-cattle-be-singular

Comment: @tchrist I know that it should be "cattle graze"...I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that. Blame it on too much whisky at a friend's 75th B'day